# How can I remove username from title on profile page?

Tags: 8, users

I am trying to remove the user name from the users profile page. I tried to remove the div using CSS, but it is the same div as for all other nodes, so this means all other titles disappear. I only want to remove the user name on the profile page. I am using the module Real Name, so this is the last place where the user name is visible. I have only found tips for drupal7 dated years back when googling. Any ideas on how this could be done?
[image: profile page]

Comment: Just wanted to note that using CSS to hide page elements doesn't actually _hide_ them. For this, you should use template overrides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered now that "Page Title" is in a block in Drupal 8. I set this block to not show on /user/*, which worked great.